# Enforcing strict comparison for bool return type functions in PHP

Tags: php, strict

Given:
 `if ($var)` is a loose comparison as in `if ($var == true)`

strict comparison will be
`if ($var === true)`

should also `bool` return type function be explicitly enforced?

es:

`if (isset($var) === true)` or `if (isset($var) === false)`

`if ($this->isEnabled($var) === true)` or `if ($this->isEnabled($var) === false)`

instead of:

`if (isset($var))` or `if (!isset($var))`

`if ($this->isEnabled($var))` or `if (!$this->isEnabled($var))`

considering it as good practice to use strict comparison and improve readability?

PS: the above functions are just for example

Comment: [isset()](https://www.php.net/isset) returns bool. It cannot return anything else. There's nothing to enforce.

Comment: Strict type comparison is faster. That 's the only reason I 'd recommend it. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401478/why-is-faster-than-in-php

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I see your point but `isset` is only an example. What about a user function like `isEnabled()`, would you trust the semantic only or enforce it?

Comment: @apedic do you mean [this function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ui-control.isenabled.php)? If so then, again, it always returns a bool so you don't need to worry. If you want to talk about a function whose return value can be of different types, then it might become more useful.

Comment: @ADyson sorry I edited, in general I mean any user function `isSomething()` where not necessarily you know if the return type is strict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a loosely typed language, thus you need strict comparisons, right?

Well, no. Not at least in every single place where boolean logic is involved.

The only case where you ever need to make a strict comparison against a boolean value is when the function can return two different falsy (or truthy) values that you want to distinguish. A typical case is [mysqli_fetch_assoc()](https://php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc):

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns an associative array representing the fetched row, where each key in the array represents the name of one of the result set's columns, `null` if there are no more rows in the result set, or `false` on failure.

When using it, you absolutely need to determine whether you don't have any rows or the function call failed*.

<sup>(*) Let's pretend that mysqli is not configured to throw exceptions on errors.</sup>

```
var_dump((bool)null, (bool)false);
```

```
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

You say that [isset()](https://php.net/isset) is just an example, but it's an example where you do not *need* strict comparison, because it cannot return a non-boolean:

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns `true` if var exists and has any value other than `null`. `false` otherwise.

You need strict comparisons when automatic type casting is not desired. Look at this:

```
$pin = '000123';
if ($pin == '123' ) {
    echo "PIN is correct\n";
}
```

```
PIN is correct
```

---

Is it good practice to do it everywhere, needed or not?

I've seen developers arguing that this improves readability:

```
if ($order->hasInvoice() === true) {
}
```

That's subjective and I won't pontificate on it, but this style also leads to:

```
if ($order->hasInvoice() === false) {
}
```

Just decide whether you find that more readable than:

```
if (!$order->hasInvoice()) {
}
```

Comment: Technically it's and was all clear for me, question regards readability and consistency only. If I use strict comparison only, I think using it everywhere keep the code style consistent, but I understand at this point it's only an opinion

Answer (score 0):

For bools there is no performance difference between strict and loose comparisons. The code readability is more important. The rule of thumb is the less expressions the code is easier to read.

Answer (score -1):

The `if(isset($var))` can also check if the value is defined. I would prefer using the function `is_bool()` first, then checking if it is true/false. By checking if the value is of type `Boolean`, you remove the doubt and can also handle other types using an `else`.